# Question directed to someone or at someone?

Tags: prepositions

> That question was directed at Sasha

OR

> That question was directed to Sasha

what is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct usage is `at Sasha`. You direct *at* a person, but *to* a location.

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, 'at' is the correct usage.

'to' is appropriate only when the question is going to be sent rather than asked aloud:

> After the meeting, the questions were distributed. All the questions about health were directed to Sasha.

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid.

As reported from the New Oxford American Dictionary,

> He directed his criticism at media coverage of the Catholic Church.
>   I suggest that he direct his remarks to the council.

Both the sentences are valid. In those sentences, *direct* means *direct a comment/question to or aim a criticism to*.