# What preposition goes after “directed”?

Tags: prepositions

Is there a comprehensive explanation of which prepositions I should use with *directed*, and why?

- directed at
- directed to
- directed on
- directed onto
- directed in
- directed into
- directed toward
- directed towards
- ... ?

I have found two possible answers, but they look just “partial” in my case:

- [Question directed to someone or at someone?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10027/question-directed-to-someone-or-at-someone)
- [“Directed at” vs. “directed towards”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46055/directed-at-vs-directed-towards)

Comment: There's a question on [“toward” vs. “towards”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286/toward-or-towards), too. [Two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/toward-or-towards-what-would-a-native-speaker-use), actually.

Comment: Directed around.  Directed under.  Directed over.  Directed through.

Comment: You need to be a *lot* more specific about the context in which you want to use "directed" - every one of your prepositions occurs in at last some constructions that many native speakers would consider unremarkable.

Comment: @GEdgar: don't forget "directed by". Or, as Robusto put it in chat, it's hard to think of a preposition that *can't* be used after "directed". We really need context, moudrick.

Comment: I don't think think I've heard of "directed on."